# GNU Scientific Library will not load in Qt

Tags: qt, dll, plugins, gsl

So I am making a Windows Qt App with Qt Creator. This app use some home-made some plugins that are loaded dynamically at startup.

One of those plugins uses the GNU Scientific Library. When I have code in that plugin that calls stuff from the GSL, loading fails, and I get a log warning in my app (and anything related to the plugin isn't there/doesn't work). When I comment out that GSL code, loading succeeds.

Since I have to pass this project around to others or commit it on some server I am using a pre-compiled DLL and the headers (which I put in my own source folder) instead of the entire uncompiled source. DLL found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm).

I am guessing that somehow the GSL is missing some dependencies or not loading properly. Does anyone have experience or ideas to share with that ?

I am also trying to build a dummy C++ project to see what's exactly not working. This dummy isn't even a Qt app, it's just a dull C++ console project with only a main with some calls to some gsl functions. Now here Qt Creator fails to compile because when it includes the header files from the gsl and parses them, it fails on all the internal includes inside them (no such file or directory). They look like

```
#include <gsl/gsl_some_content.h>
```

Why does it fail there and not in my Qt App project ? If I hardcore-replace those includes with

```
#include "gsl_some_content.h"
```

Then it compiles but exits at runtime with code -1073741515, without showing any printfs (even if I have them at the very start of the main). Again, if I comment out the gsl parts of the main, everything works normally and the printfs show.

EDIT : one more piece of info : dumpbin /dependents gives me an error :

```
Dump of file libgsl-19.dll

File Type: DLL

LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during DumpSections

  Version 9.00.30729.01

  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
  ExceptionAddress         = 009671A0 (00940000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe"
  NumberParameters         = 00000002
  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00000004

CONTEXT:
  Eax    = 40000040  Esp    = 001CDDB0
  Ebx    = 02943A08  Ebp    = 001CDDD8
  Ecx    = 00000004  Esi    = 00000004
  Edx    = 0094405C  Edi    = 0000014C
  Eip    = 009671A0  EFlags = 00010246
  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

Thanks in advance,

Charles

Comment: Poke around with the `ldd` tool.

Comment: Isn't that a Linux tool ? I'm on Windows ... and if it were a missing dependency wouldn't not start at all rather than exit with a weird code or not load or whatever ?